# Suppressing linebreak when entering environment

Tags: latex, newline

In the following LaTeX fragment, how can I suppress the newline that is automatically generated between XXX and YYY after entering the `align*` environment.

```
XXX
\begin{minipage}{t}{0.1in}
  YYY
  \begin{align*}
     ZZZ...
  \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
```

yields

```
XXX YYY
ZZZ...
```

But I want

```
XXX YYY ZZZ...
```

Perhaps `align*` is simply the wrong environment, but I couldn't find an alternative that provides similar functionality, yet doesn't introduce a linebreak.

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of what you're trying to achieve with this? The `align` environment is for multi-line equations, I can't think of a scenario where one would need the first line to be in-line with some preceding text.

Comment: I tried to be suggestive with the use of the align environment to mean that something has to be aligned in there. But you actually gave a reason why my approach did not work: I did not know that `align` environment was only for multi-line equations. Will then offered the missing piece.

Comment: Note your example will give (after s/{t}/[t]/) a linebreak between XXX and YYY as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure if it's supposed to be used like this, but perhaps the `aligned` environment is what you're after?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
XXX
\begin{minipage}[t]{1in}
YYY
$
  \begin{aligned}
     ZZZ...
  \end{aligned}
$
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed. I did not know that the aligned environment existed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason Latex forces a linebreak when entering the minipage environment is that you move from entering text in horizontal mode, to introducing a new paragraph-like environment, minipage.  You can stop this linebreak by using `\vbox{...}`, so:

```
XXX
\vbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{2in} % Note that the first parameter is optional
  YYY
  ...
\end{minipage}
}
```

`\vbox` won't stop the align environment's linebreak, though, because that is explicitly made by with the environment's Tex code: for that use Will's suggestion of using aligned.

Comment: In my case I needed `\hbox` instead of `\vbox`

Answer (score 0):

For single-line, in-line equations, you can use the `$` math environment delimiter:

```
XXX
\begin{minipage}{t}{0.1in}
    YYY $ZZZ...$
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what you want—why are you using `align`?  What is it that needs aligning?

Maybe you're looking for [`tabbing`](http://www.tac.dk/cgi-bin/info2www?%28latex%29tabbing) in Latex?

```
\begin{tabbing}
text \= more text \= still more text \= last text \\
second row \>  \> more \\
.
.
.
\end{tabbing}
```

Comment: Apologies for being a little too short with my example, but what you describe comes in handy as well.

Comment: No problem.  For typesetting math, I recommend Mathmode by Hervert Voss a lot.